# Prevent line-breaks copied to the clipboard in grid layout

Tags: css, css-grid, chromium

I'm working with a given HTML structure that I **cannot modify**. Through CSS, I arranged elements in a grid layout that visually suits my needs, but when copying the text, a line break is added between each block, which I don't want.

Below is an example:

```css
div {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
}
span { display: block }
```

```html
<div>
  <span>1</span><span>+</span><span>3</span><span>=</span><span>4</span>
</div>
```

With Chromium 79, when selecting, copying to the clipboard and then pasting it somewhere,
the result is as follows:

```
1
+
3
=
4
```

In FireFox 72, I get what I want:

```
1+3=4
```

Comment: I think this is only partially related to the source. Indeed I did copy the text from the example from chrome, and then tried to paste it in notepad, notepad++, excel and word; The result in word was "1 + 3 = 4" while in other softwares this was indeed pasted with a line break as you state.

Comment: I should probably mention that I am on Linux and I am actually targetting Discord, which uses electron, but the problem is general enough, I think.

Comment: Why do you need to copy the output and paste it somewhere else?

Comment: Because Discord is a messaging app and I tend to copy things (specifically old messages) to refer to them.

Answer (score 0):

I used this method, with React and MUI (but not required):

1. Add an invisible special character as the new-line replacement at the end of each row such as:

```
<Box
    sx={{
    color: 'transparent',
    '&::selection': {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
    }}
>
    ↵
</Box>
```

2. Then on the copy event:

```
  const onCopy = async () => {
    const text = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
    const fixed = text
      // Split lines
      .split('↵')
      // Replace new line from grid cells
      .map((l) => l.replace(/\r?\n/g, ' ').replace(/ +/g, ' ').trim())
      // Rejoin the lines
      .join('\n');
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText(fixed);
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

Selection content wont harm you anyway,  but still adding one small solution to tackle:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
  display:inline-block;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>+</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>=</span>
  <span>4</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

)

Comment: The later `display` property overrides the earlier, so this isn't a grid anymore.

Comment: yup !, i dont think grid can handle this !